# When debugging Javascript in Chrome Devtools, how can I continue after hitting a DOM breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a JS code with Chrome Devtools. I set a DOM breakpoint, the code hit it, but I cannot continue (ie, the controls for "next line", "continue", etc. are missing)...I could only run my code again after closing the browser and opening it again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controls aren't shown in the DOM window, but you can continue in two ways:

1. In the window you're debugging, in the center at the top, there should be a small overlay saying "Paused in debugger" with a run icon. Click the run icon.
2. Switch to the Sources tab, which has the various buttons, and use one of those.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting, but now it's not breaking in the breakpoint...Do you know any resource (eg video) that goes more into detail on DOM breakpoints?

Comment: @MrT77 - Odd that it's not stopping on the breakpoint. Do you have devtools open? Have you disabled breakpoints? I don't know of any specific resources, other than [this tutorial from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom) (they list the tutorial as "deprecated" but I don't know why, fairly sure DOM breakpoints themselves are *not* deprecated).

Comment: (Side note: You can't accept an answer within 15 minutes of asking the question, SO won't let you. :-) )

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear explanation, but it's not stopping at the DOM breakpoint...

Comment: @MrT77 - Then the condition the breakpoint is triggered by is not occurring. Chrome's devtools are not completely error-free, but (with apologies!) the odds are **dramatically** higher that they're working correctly and you don't have the breakpoint set correctly than that the breakpoint is set correctly and not firing. [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). :-) Anyway, the question was about continuing, not hitting the breakpoint. If you can't figure it out, post a question with an MCVE and someone will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sure it is my fault, I just haven't found what is my error! (btw, I edited my question to show what I'm doing, as I can't put pictures here in comments)

Comment: @MrT77 :-) Questions shoudln't be moving targets. Your original question is answered. If you have a new question, please post a new question. (And if you do, be sure to say what attribute you're changing, and how you're changing it. Note that the current value of an `input` is **not an attribute**. Changing an `input`'s value doesn't change the DOM at all.)

Comment: You're completely right! My error (for the 2nd question) was that: attribute modification doesn't track the current value! (I'm editing my 1st question again so not to confuse other users). Thanks

Comment: @MrT77 - Yeah, that one trips people up. :-) *Most* of the time, a property (like `src` on `img` elements) reflects the attribute with the same name, but not always. The `value` attribute of an `input` is its *default* value (available on the `input` element as the `defaultValue` property), not its current value, and the current value isn't an attribute at all. (Some of this stuff wasn't as thoroughly designed as it might have been... ;-) )